# How to get the inequalities

Tags: inequality

I have this set:

> $(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \{(0,1,1),(1,1,0),(0,0,1),(1,1,1)\}$

How to get the set of inequalities that above set is its answer?

Comment: What's the question, it's unclear. **Please clarify your question**

Answer (score 1):

$(x_1^2+(x_2-1)^2+(x_3-1)^2)\cdot((x_1-1)^2+(x_2-1)^2+x_3^2)\cdot(x_1^2+x_2^2+(x_3-1)^2)\cdot((x_1-1)^2+(x_2-1)^2+(x_3-1)^2)\le 0$